# как воссоздать исторические события через анализ древнерусских слов

Tags: этимология, история

Один человек как-то сказал, что вся правда осталась в современной "изуродованной" версии славянского языка, "и её у нас не отнять".

Какие методы мне стоит использовать, чтобы узнать в подробностях истинную историю человечества или русского народа по средством разбора слов и словообразования?

Comment: Этот человек ошибался.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разбирая слова, историю народа и человечества не выучишь. Может быть, Вы имели в виду модный сейчас  интерес к ведической культуре славян – истокам формирования древнеславянского мировоззрения. Сейчас публикуется немало научно аргументированных трудов по этой теме. Наблюдается рост общественного интереса к исследованию праязыка и лингвистической семантике, раскрывающей глубинный скрытый смысл языка, носителями которого мы являемся.

Если Вас это интересует, обратитесь к ведическим сайтам, вот сюда хотя бы

http://kpe.ru/sobytiya-i-mneniya/ocenka-sostavlyayuschih-jizni-obschestva/mirovozzrenie-nauka-obrazovanie/2524-secret

Почитайте об истории славянской письменности, там много чего интересного, только такие вещи нужно читать осторожно, потому что много "околонаучных" трудов, основанных на фантазиях, случайных совпадениях и собственных домыслах. Если хотите заниматься наукой, и методы должны быть научные - изучение древнерусского языка - лексики и грамматики, чтение источников, попытки перевода. Если осилите, удачи, а нет, лучше читайте готовую литературу, в сети её много, но пытайтесь отделить научные статьи от фантазий. Некоторые "статейки"откровенно националистические, обвиняющие всех и вся в переиначивании истории, а сами этим и занимаются.

Answer (score 3):

Не знаю, что имел в виду тот человек, но интерпретация ваша явно ошибочна.

Могу предположить, что в лучшем случае речь шла о каком-то анализе культурного-социального уклада общества. И использовать, конечно, надо язык той эпохи, а не современный нам. Например, наличие в языке хорошо развитой системы сельскохозяйственных орудий и процессов может показать, что цивилизация была аграрной, развитая система именования родственников (вот это уж точно про славян) может опосредовано показать систему родо-племенных отношений народа даже в бесписьменную эпоху. Исторические же события никак из языка не реконструируются.

Другой вариант тот, что из легенд и былин можно как-то понять историю народа. Так, общность мифов разных народов даёт некоторые основания полагать о существовании какого-то события, лежащего в их основе. Но это тоже весьма косвенное свидетельство с точки зрения научно-исторического подхода.

Все это, впрочем, лишь второстепенные, вспомогательные методы исследования. В любом случае никакие грамматические методы тут не помогут.